# How can I rotate my display using some GUI tool, in LXDE?

Tags: gui, lxde, display-settings

I'm using LXDE. Is there a utility, menu item or other GUI-ish way to rotate the display on my monitor (e.g. by 90 degrees)? `lxrandr` doesn't seem to offer me that option.

My system is Debian Stretch 64bit, it's some kind of Intel Graphics on-board chip, and the monitor is a Dell U2312. It works on Windows.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `arandr`, a GUI front end for `xrandr`. This also is capable of rotating the screen. It is in the Debian repositories.

[Arandr's web page](https://christian.amsuess.com/tools/arandr/#similar-projects) also mentions alternative GUI tools, no idea how up to date that is.

Answer (score 4):

The good tool for this job is `xrandr`.

First determine your display with something like

```
$ xrandr --verbose | awk '/ connected/{print $1}'
LVDS1
```

Now you are ready to play with it

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --rotate left
xrandr --output LVDS1 --rotate inverted
xrandr --output LVDS1 --reflect x
xrandr --output LVDS1 --reflect xy
```

and when you mess your screen too much just run

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --rotate normal
xrandr --output LVDS1 --reflect normal
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to find out how the screen that you want to rotate is labeled.:

```
xrandr -q
```

Output should be something like:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS1 connected 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
1366x768 60.1*+
1360x768 59.8 60.0
1024x768 60.0
800x600 60.3 56.2
640x480 59.9
VGA2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

This will give you connected monitors  It says connected next to the name. Determine the one that you want to rotate.
 Next, we want to turn it around. For that, we use one of the following

```
xrandr --output <label>  --rotate right
    xrandr --output <label>  --rotate left
    xrandr --output <label> --rotate inverted
    xrandr --output <label> --rotate normal
```

Of course replace    with your monitor label in the above commands and you'll be able to rotate the screen.

Comment: And there's no GUI for that? :-(

Comment: Not that i know of but yo can set up a hot key for the command